# how do i fetch a single category from an arrayObj of categories?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

I do have the category id and I can also fetch singleCategory but i'm unable to fetch the product arrayObj within the categories arrayObj?
i want to create a single category page which displays all products in the selected category
all the requests and data is fetched from commerce.js api

```
import { Grid, Container, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Product from "../Product";
import Spinner from "../Spinner";
import Banner from "../Banner";
import "./style.css";

const Products = ({ categories, addProduct }) => {
    const [singleCategory, setSingleCategory] = useState({});

    const fetchCategory = async (id) => {
      const response = await commerce.categories.retrieve(id);

      setSingleCategory({ response });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const id = window.location.pathname.split("/");
      fetchCategory(id[2]);
    }, []);

    console.log(singleCategory)
    console.log(categories)

  if (!categories.length) return <Spinner />;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Banner />
      <div id="products">
        {categories.map((category, index) =>
          category.productsData.length ? (
            <div
              key={category.id}
              className="contents"
              style={{
                backgroundImage:
                  index % 2 !== 0
                    ? "linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3d4a5d,#3d4a5d, #bb86fc)"
                    : "",
              }}
            >
              <Container>
                <Link className="headline" to={`category-view/${category.id}`}>
                  <Typography className="headline" variant="h3" component="h2">
                    {category.name}
                  </Typography>
                </Link>
                <Grid container spacing={4}>
                  {category.productsData.map((product) => (
                    <Grid key={product.id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                      <Product
                        product={product}
                        addProduct={addProduct}
                        categoryName={category.name}
                      />
                    </Grid>
                  ))}
                </Grid>
              </Container>
            </div>
          ) : null
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Products;
```

this is my app.js

```
const App = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data: products } = await commerce.products.list({ limit: 1000 });
    const { data: categoriesData } = await commerce.categories.list();
    
    const productsPerCategory = categoriesData.reduce((acc, category) => {
      return [
        ...acc,
        {
          ...category,
          productsData: products.filter((product)=>
          product.categories.find((cat) => cat.id === category.id)),
        },
      ];
    }, []);
      
    setCategories(productsPerCategory);
  };
```

Comment: What does products and categoriesData contain?

Comment: im fetching an array of all products in 'product' and 'categoriesData' contains an array of all the categories, and when im setting 'setCategories' it contains an array of categoriesData which contains an array of product